# What we call :: in C#?

Tags: c#, .net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Scope-resolution operator :: versus member-access operator . in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4731501/scope-resolution-operator-versus-member-access-operator-in-c)

What we call ::  in following example?

```
  MyNamespace.Properties.Resources.myImage;     

  global::MyNamespace.Properties.Resources.myImage;
```

Comment: Duplicate of my own question, [Scope-resolution operator `::` versus member-access operator `.` in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4731501/scope-resolution-operator-versus-member-access-operator-in-c)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We call it the [namespace alias qualifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/htccxtad.aspx).